# How to reset v-bind after submit?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vee-validate

How to reset v-bind after submit?

```
<Field name="name" v-slot={field}>
  <ion-input ref="name" name="name" v-bind="field" placeholder="Nome"></ion-input>
</Field>
```

resetForm() reset v-slot but v-bind="field" keep the value inside the input.

Before reset:

[image]

After reset:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are not binding the variable to any specific attribute.

The syntax `v-bind` is simply the long form of `:`.

It needs a suffix to denote the attribute.

For example `v-bind:value="field"` to bind to the value.

In shorthand you would write this as just `:value="field"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I don't have problems when i use v-bind. I just don't know how to reset the v-bind in my methods (in the case, onSubmit) or access them.

Comment: You would need to reset the value of the `field` variable. For example, if you bind the value of the input to `field` and then you change the `field` variable it will be updated in the component. How are you updating the `field` variable?

Comment: The `field` variable is updated when I write, automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the variable you have bound

```js
clear () {
    this.field = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can't access the `field` variable with `this` but i already used a workaround.